# TimeSpan > 24 hours

Tags: asp.net, timespan

I have the

```
Dim time As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds)
Return time.ToString
```

that gives me the result in the d.HH:mm:ss format.
But, I don't need the number of days instead I would like to have f.e. `40:25:36` which means 40 hours, 25 min and 36sec.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds).TotalDays
```

returns the (fractional) number of days of a timespan